# How to set unique for column in Parse.com - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, unique

Now, I using [Parse.com](https://www.back4app.com/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwqYfWBRDPARIsABjQRYwXOdyhlbtJmLzGhx37BfZ2se7vuvZ7Nx_vSjJufJfpDe1ehlD5pAoaAsJKEALw_wcB) server to save my data, everything is fine but I don't know how to set unique for column in table. Plz help, thank you very much.